# How do I define an array of optional items, where each item has its own schema?

Tags: jsonschema

I have the use case where an array can optionally contain items, but each item when present needs to comply to its own defined schema. I tried this:

```json
{
    "plugins": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": [
            {
                "$ref": "plugins/oidc/oidc_apigw-plugin-schema.json"
            },
            {
                "$ref": "plugins/oidc/oidc_websso-plugin-schema.json"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

but it does not meet the requirements, since it is expecting those two items in that specific order. It must be something related to this https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html, but I have no idea how to apply it correctly. Here my attempt:

```json
{
    "plugins": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": [
            {
                "type": "object"
            }
        ],
        "dependentSchemas": {
            "oidc_apigw": {
                "$ref": "plugins/oidc/oidc_apigw-plugin-schema.json"
            },
            "oidc_websso": {
                "$ref": "plugins/oidc/oidc_websso-plugin-schema.json"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `contains` keyword to specify "this schema should match, but the item can appear anywhere in the list". Combine it with `minContains` if you want to indicate that the item should appear more than once.

https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html